# How to set boolean to false in methods in Smali code

Tags: java, android, smali

There is only one boolean that I need to set to false. This value is then returned when this method is called. But I have no experience of Smali so I need help. I decompiled apk to both java code (to know what to look for) and Smali (to edit and recompile). Here is the method in java code:

```
public PendingResult<Status> setMockMode(GoogleApiClient client, boolean isMockMode) {
        return client.zzb(new C06163(this, client, isMockMode));
    }
```

I want to change `isMockMode` in `return` to `false` but its very confusing in smali. Here is smali code of same java code:

```
.method public setMockMode(Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult;
    .locals 1
    .parameter "client"
    .parameter "isMockMode"
    .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Signature;
        value = {
            "(",
            "Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;",
            "Z)",
            "Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult",
            "<",
            "Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/Status;",
            ">;"
        }
    .end annotation

    .prologue
    new-instance v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/zzd$3;

    invoke-direct {v0, p0, p1, p2}, Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/zzd$3;-><init>(Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/zzd;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;Z)V

    invoke-virtual {p1, v0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;->zzb(Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlb$zza;)Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlb$zza;

    move-result-object v0

    return-object v0
.end method
```

Code is way too complex in Smali for me to understand. So some help please :)

Comment: @Vince Emigh please help man, I know its not translation service pretty well. There are no good guides to start learning smali. And I just need to edit this one file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope the following is self-explanatory.

```
.method public setMockMode(Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult;
    # change here 1 -> 2 to allow for another local variable v1
    .locals 2
    .prologue

    new-instance v0, Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/zzd$3;

    # add this line: v1 = 0; 0 is 'false'
    const/4 v1, 0x0

    # pass v1, which is set to 'false', instead of p2 containing isMockMode
    invoke-direct {v0, p0, p1, v1}, Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/zzd$3;-><init>(Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/zzd;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;Z)V
    invoke-virtual {p1, v0}, Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;->zzb(Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlb$zza;)Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlb$zza;
    move-result-object v0
    return-object v0
.end method
```